# Como puedo obtener solo los usuarios con rol de User_role?

Tags: nodejs, express, mongoose

### modelo:

```
 const usuarioSchema = Schema(
  {
    ...Otros campos,

    rol: [
      {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Rol",
      },
    ],
    estado: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },

    ...Otros campos,
);
```

### Query:

```
const [usuarios, total] = await Promise.all([
      User.find(conditions)
        .skip(Number(page) - 1)
        .limit(Number(limit))
        .populate("rol"),
      User.countDocuments(conditions),
    ]);
```

#### En la variable 'conditions' es solo "{estado: true}", de esa manera obtengo todos los usuarios con estado en true, yo necesito filtrar para obtener solo los usuarios con rol 'USER_ROLE'

En el modelo de Rol solo tengo un campo 'nombre' ###

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que estas usando un Promise.all() el cual no le veo mucho sentido, si te fijas bien lo que estas guardando en el modelo de usuario en rol es un array que contiene un _id (que hace mongodb por defecto) del modelo Rol al que le haces un ref. Por lo que para filtrar por usuarios que tengan el rol que quieres lo que necesitas es pasarle ese _id cuando haces un query, la forma mas sencilla seria:

```
// Primero haciendo una query del nombre del rol que quiero filtrar
const rol = await Rol.findOne({name: 'USER_ROLE'})
// Luego hago la query buscando por su _id
const users = await User.find({rol: [`${rol._id}`] }).populate('Rol')
// Esto devolvera solo los usuarios que tienen el rol USER_ROLE que dices que tiene tu base de datos
```

Tambien existe una libreria que se llama mongoose-paginate-v2 que sirve como plugin para que mongoose genere una paginacion ya que como lo estas haciendo tu segun la doc de mongoose genera problemas de performance

```
// Otra cosa aca le faltaba el new 
const usuarioSchema = new Schema(
  {
    ...Otros campos,

    rol: [
      {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Rol",
      },
    ],
    estado: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },

    ...Otros campos,
);
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada, un placer poder ayudarte! saludos